# Creating Newsfeed for Spring application

Tags: spring

I am trying to create a news feed for my Java (Spring) based application. Whenever any action occurs, I want it to show up in the news feed. 
 Should I set the database polling after regular interval? What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: You say "whenever any action occurs". How do these actions get into the system?

Comment: Maybe Spring Data Auditing is a solution for you. See [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/jpa/example/src/main/java/example/springdata/jpa/auditing)